# Replace not working in 'AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "");' only when I run using VSTest agent from Azure Devops. why?

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-devops, vstest

Here is the code:

```
            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            ITakesScreenshot ts = (ITakesScreenshot)driver;
            Screenshot screenshot = ts.GetScreenshot();
            string pth = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;
            //var dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pth).Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "");
            //dir = dir.Replace("file:\\", "");
            var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "");
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(dir + "\\Execution_Screenshots\\");
            string finalpth = pth.Substring(0, pth.LastIndexOf("bin")) + "Execution_Screenshots/" + screenShotName+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss-fff") + ".jpg";
            localpath = new Uri(finalpth).LocalPath;
            screenshot.SaveAsFile(localpath, ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

This code works when I run my tests locally. Works when I login to remote machine and run VSTest there using CLI. But when i ran this from devops using VSTest agent task, the 'Execution_Screenshots' folder gets created inside Debug folder. Replace doesn't work. Why would it not work?

Comment: What’s the error?

Comment: please find the log below:

2020-05-04T08:18:02.6078370Z   Error Message:
2020-05-04T08:18:02.6441128Z    System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\azagent\A1\_work\r1\a\_App QA Automation-IVP-CI\QA\release\Execution_Screenshots\ScreenShot_04-05-2020-01-18-01-212.jpg'.
2020-05-04T08:18:02.6759736Z   Stack Trace:
2020-05-04T08:18:02.6877435Z      at AresRobo.Hooks.Capture(IWebDriver driver, String screenShotName) in C:\Users\vmadhani\source\repos\AresRobo\Framework\Hooks.cs:line 372

Comment: Instead of folder being created in release folder, it was created in Debug folder, the part that should have been replaced in the code above

Comment: Given that its a System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException, I would suggest that the one of the directories is not present. Have you tried navigating to the C:\azagent\A1_work\r1\a_App QA Automation-IVP-CI\QA\release\Execution_Screenshots\ to make sure that it exists?

Comment: its so freaking strange. I found the issue. the folder everywhere is present as "bin/Debug"
but ONLY and ONLY when running through azure devops, path is being taken as "bin/debug"
and replace method is case sensitive. Its more like a bug in AZD.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. the path is bin/Debug. You can set system.debug variable to true, then run pipeline and provide the log of build and test here.

Comment: Would you mind to provide the detail log of build and test tasks here?